# Using transistors to control a 555 timer in astable configuration

Tags: transistors

This is a condensed circuit used for hardware debugging purposes.

The goal of this circuit is to control the 555 timer with only three pushbuttons. I am using the 555 timer and resistors to simulate the signal source I will be using. This is not a high-powered system therefore I do not see the need to use relays.

When the button is pushed the microcontroller will receive a digital signal to turn on the LED. At the same time, this push button will be used to allow the 555 timer to produce the desired frequency. On a fundamental level, it is combining a simple push-button circuit with the 555 timer piano circuit only difference is that these buttons need to be shared.

To start I got all of the pushbuttons working with the Arduino. Then I connected one transistor to the 555 timers and the capacitor charged and discharged appropriately to give the desired frequency.

When I connected the other transistors shown in the circuit below, the capacitor charges but it does not fully discharge to create the signal for buttons 02 and buttons 03. However, button 01 still works.

[image]

- Why this is the case?
- Why does the first circuit work and the second one not work?

Comment: Schematics please and not cartoons or artist's impressions of a breadboard. Also, what has "arbitrary signal" got to do with a 555?

Comment: So you are making a NE555 astable. You pictures are too small to see clearly. Can you show us a schematic, indicating which R1, R2, C1 values you are using to fix the frequency of the oscillator?

Comment: Or you might like to refer to my NE555 astable circuit and let me know if it is similar to yours and the values you are using for your R1, R2, and C1: https://i.imgur.com/oEyZowH.jpeg.

Comment: I will update the question accordingly

Comment: David, most of those wiring diagram generators can export a schematic which will need some tidy up to make it readable. You can make one by using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: @DavidWisniewski:  What you have posted are wiring diagrams. They are used to show how to assemble a circuit.  Schematic diagrams show the functional aspects of the circuit.  As it stands, anyone who wants to help you first has to translate your wiring diagram to a schematic diagram. It is better if you provide the schematic.  You are asking for help, so it is in your interest to make it easy for others to help.  Also, you have the circuit already in a design program.  It should be pretty straight forward for you to generate a schematic from your existing file.

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome to the community

Comment: I've re-read your question, and it seems like it boils down to "my Arduino controlled 555 timer isn't working," at which point I have to ask why you even have the 555 in there at all.  The Arduino can generate any square wave that the 555 can, and do it better.  Is the output not a square wave?

Comment: Thank you for replacing the wiring diagrams with schematic diagrams.

Comment: Thank you for recommending that action I was able to learn a lot form those couple of hours I spent working on it. I wasn`t able to find out too much about the circuit lab but I will look into it for future posts.

Comment: The reason why the 555 Timer is being used is because it produces an output similar to the package I am working with when in this astable configuration. It also makes debugging the circuit easier. I could use the Arduino for testing but I need those pins open for the time being.

Comment: @DavidWisniewski could you elaborate on that? "An output similar to the package I am working with": So you're simulating a 555 with a 555? also, I'd be interested what "I could use the Arduino for testing, but I need those pins open" means, exactly? (I just don't understand that sentence :( )

Comment: The Arduino is being used to power an LCD display and is also being used to control some minor circuit elements in the finished design. The module I am using produces 3 different frequencies other than that I know how to use it and wire it up but I have not reached that phase in the design process yet. Being I can't get a simple 555 timer to work. I believe adding in those additional circuit elements would lead to misunderstandings as to what I want to accomplish.

Comment: I am relatively new to electronics but being that these elements in the final design do not interact with each other I thought it would be safe to exclude them.

Comment: @DavidWisniewski I feel like all that you describe suggests that the 555 is an obstacle, not a bridge towards your goal.

Comment: @David Wisniewski, your "schematic" is a bit confusing. I have redrawn it with some simplification and modifications. ***My schematic is made public***, so you can copy and paste it in your EE SE account, and ***open it and edit in your own editor***. Please feel free to make any any changes. https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/xmp5pk4edhp5/ne555-astable-design-v0_1-2020oct1101/. Happy circuit drawing. Cheers.  PS - ***You can also make comments or propose changes to my drawing***. I will try to draw a new version and let you comment again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your MCU connections to the buttons/LEDs is faulty in that each MCU output connects through a resistor to ground (shown in purple below): -

[image]

And, each time you press one of the buttons, it will short out the 5 volt power rail.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why only one push-button worked was due to the transistors not getting the .7V that they needed to operate. This was fixed by simply readjusting the resistor values. So that the transistors had .7V on the base terminal. The [Schematic](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/xmp5pk4edhp5/ne555-astable-design-v0_1-2020oct1101/) made by  @ tlfong01  helped lead to this answer.
This is a picture from an [online](https://www.explainthatstuff.com/howtransistorswork.html) recource explaining why this is the case.
[image]